# How casperjs passing arguments with space?

Tags: casperjs

```
casperjs script.js "myurl" "myemail" "my name"
```

Here is the script:

```
url = (casper.cli.get(0));
email = (casper.cli.get(1));
name = (casper.cli.get(2));

this.echo(name);
console.log(name);
```

The result is: `my` (and not `my name`).

I also tried with single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just escape the spaces with a backslash and DON'T use quotes, for example:

```
 casperjs test.js myurl myemail my\ name
```

I don't know for sure if it is dependend to the console you are using, under ubuntu (docker) that worked for me:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var targetUrl = 'http://www.test.com/';

casper.start(targetUrl, function() {
  url = (casper.cli.get(0));
  email = (casper.cli.get(1));
  name = (casper.cli.get(2));
  this.echo(url);
  this.echo(email);
  this.echo(name);
  console.log(name);
});

casper.run();
```

Result was:

```
myurl
myemail
my name
my name
```

For a windows command line that worked:

```
casperjs test.js myurl myemail \"my name\"
```

Comment: How would you do this on Windows?

Comment: Update: Escapes for a windows command line added to the post.

Comment: wow haha so simple I can't believe I was cracking my head over that ; ; thanks!

Comment: you are welcome! when you got a solution for the power shell, let me know! :D

Comment: This worked for me in power shell: casperjs --% test casper.js --foo=\"space bar\"